# Can Proteus Isis open Eagle's schematic?

Tags: schematics, eaglecad, layout, proteus

I had some years working with Proteus PCB design. A few years then, I did not do the same work.

Now, from Googling, electronics community seem to place Eagle in a dominating position. Sparkfun, Arduino open-source projects are released in Eagle.

Should I switch to use Eagle? or Proteus Isis has some function to import Eagle schematic?

Comment: Why have you not seen at schematic's format? Does the proteus has it's format in the open window? Also you can easy download the eagle and use of it for your job.

Comment: Without more details this is far too opinion based.  With your specific requirements for a PCB package including features, compatibility and price range it might be less so.

Comment: @Roh: for me, when I'm familiar with one CAD tool, it's not that easy to switch to another since I'm even used to the shortcut keys and operations that related to schematic or PCB layout

Comment: @David: since there's a dominating trend to share designs in Eagle, is there a solution for Proteus users to join this trend without having to switch to using Ealge? that's what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has two parts, the fist part (best software) is a matter of preference so there is no point sharing my personal opinion although I don't see why it is a problem using both and you need to choose one or the other.

In your second question about importing Eagle files in ISIS (schematic) or ARES (PCB) this is not possible, at least up to the current version 8.

Comment: thanks for the answer! that's what I want to ask. Soo... so far, there isn't any tool, patch something... that can convert between the two formats?? it's bad that I have to get familiar with another CAD tool

Comment: You don't need to learn that much about Eagle, just a few basics assuming that you only want to be able to open schematics/PCB that others made, you can keep designing your own work in ARES.
I'm not aware of any tool that can convert from one format to the other.